# External Table: VARCHAR in Create but CHAR in Access Parameters

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, table, varchar

Consider this SO Question [UTF-8 And External Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944757/handling-utf-8-characters-in-oracle-external-tables).
A proposed solution contains VARCHAR2 columns in the CREATE section but those same columns get CHAR attributes in the ACCESS PARAMETERS section.

Why the difference?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datatypes inside the database, and used by SQL*Loader or the ORACLE_LOADER driver are different.

SQL*Loader does not know the VARCHAR2 datatype. It has a VARCHAR type, but that type is nonportable, meaning it is platform dependent.

[SQL*Loader Datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1151)

> VARCHAR fields can be loaded with correct results only between systems
>   where a SHORT data field INT has the same length in bytes. If the byte
>   order is different between the systems, or if the VARCHAR field
>   contains data in the UTF16 character set, then use the appropriate
>   technique to indicate the byte order of the length subfield and of the
>   data. The byte order of the data is only an issue for the UTF16
>   character set.

The CHAR type of SQL*Loader is portable.

> **Portable Datatypes**
>
> The portable datatypes are grouped into value
>   datatypes and length-value datatypes. The portable value datatypes are
>   as follows:
>
> CHAR
>
> Datetime and Interval
>
> GRAPHIC
>
> GRAPHIC EXTERNAL
>
> Numeric EXTERNAL (INTEGER, FLOAT, DECIMAL, ZONED)
>
> RAW
>
> The portable length-value datatypes are as follows:
>
> VARCHARC
>
> VARRAWC

Using a non-portable type you may or may not be able to load the data on a different platform:

[Loading Data Across Different Platforms](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_field_list.htm#SUTIL1204)

> When a data file created on one platform is to be loaded on a
>   different platform, the data must be written in a form that the target
>   system can read. For example, if the source system has a native,
>   floating-point representation that uses 16 bytes, and the target
>   system's floating-point numbers are 12 bytes, then the target system
>   cannot directly read data generated on the source system.
>
> The best solution is to load data across an Oracle Net database link,
>   taking advantage of the automatic conversion of datatypes. This is the
>   recommended approach, whenever feasible, and means that SQL*Loader
>   must be run on the source system.
>
> Problems with interplatform loads typically occur with native
>   datatypes. In some situations, it is possible to avoid problems by
>   lengthening a field by padding it with zeros, or to read only part of
>   the field to shorten it (for example, when an 8-byte integer is to be
>   read on a system that uses 4-byte integers, or the reverse). Note,
>   however, that incompatible datatype implementation may prevent this.
>
> **If you cannot use an Oracle Net database link and the data file must
>   be accessed by SQL*Loader running on the target system, then it is
>   advisable to use only the portable SQL*Loader datatypes (for example,
>   CHAR, DATE, VARCHARC, and numeric EXTERNAL).**